# PHP Form (This address wasn't understood) on Firefox issue

Tags: php, html, firefox

-HTML code-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-justify">
<h1>Fill this form pliz</h1>
<div class="form-group">
<form name="myform" method="post" action="formdb.php">
First name:<br> <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder=" First-name" required>
<br>
Second name:<br><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder=" Second-name" required>
<br>
Age:<br><input type="number" name="age" min="15" max="100" placeholder=" Age">
<br>
Email:<br><input type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail">
<br><br>
Gender:<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other"> Other <br>

Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" placeholder=" Password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

-PHP code-

```
<?php

echo "Values recieved"."<br>";

$fname=$lname=$age=$email=$sex=$pass="";

function test_input($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=stripslashes($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    echo"bitch";
    $fname=test_input($_POST['fname']);
    $lname=test_input($_POST['lname']);
    $age=test_input($_POST['age']);
    $sex=test_input($_POST['gender']);
    $email=test_input($_POST['email']);
    $pass=test_input($_POST['password']);
}

echo "First name is ".$fname;

?>
```

When I submit the form, I get an error from Firefox saying that "This address wasn't understood".
Both the PHP and HTML are located in the same directory. Is it an issue caused by Firefox or is there an error on my part?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me -- the error is not thrown for me, even in Firefox. Therefor, this is certainly not a problem with Firefox. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Double Check:** Name of Php File is it `formdb.php`, is it located in same folder as the form?
if you run `echo basename(__DIR__);` is the form in same folder as `formdb.php`?

You can Also Check for Errors: Put This In Your Html File

```
<?PHP
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```